# SSIS add user path to project parameters in Visual Studio DEV configuration

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, ssis-2017

I am using Azure Devops in my project which means my SSIS project is stored in a file location that looks like this: C:\Users\johan\source\repos\Data Warehouse\Scripts. We are using the Project Deployment model.

In Visual Studio configuration manager I would like to make the DEV configuration dependent on the user. So for André this would change into C:\Users\andre\source\repos\Data Warehouse\Scripts and for Kasper into C:\Users\kasper\source\repos\Data Warehouse\Scripts. This would allow developers to run a changed script directly from Visual Studio. I could also have a fixed folder with scripts somewhere, but in that case a developer must copy his changed script to this folder to make it work.

I know parameters can't be variable but is there any other way to make this location dependent on the current user? These scripts are for example Powershell scripts that are executed from a package.

Comment: [System::UserName] contains the Windows login that is running the package. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Amira, Thanks for your response. I can't use System variables in parameters. I am looking for a way to do this at project level.